# What is the origin of the "iso [frequency/voltage/power]" terminology?

Tags: computer-architecture, vlsi, terminology, history, jargon

In the VLSI and computer architecture world, it is common to hear terms like "iso frequency" or "iso power" when comparing the performance of different designs.

My understanding is that "iso" here means "at the same"; e.g. discussing the performance of two different designs "iso frequency" means discussing their performance when run at the same frequency (controlling for any frequency differences between the designs).

Where does this "iso" terminology come from? Is "iso" an acronym ("ISO"), or is it shorthand for something else?

I heard this terminology used several times during the Q&A and discussion at HotChips 2020, but it is hard to find references to it on the internet and clues to the origin and meaning of "iso".

Comment: By the way, I am pretty sure "iso" in this context does not stand for the International Organization for Standardization.

Comment: The prefix iso comes from ancient greek and means "equal". Do you think that would alone provide enough explanation, or do you think there is something more to it?

Comment: @Justme, I think it really is as simple as a common Greek-derived prefix I wasn't aware of. I would encourage you to submit an answer.

Comment: I don't know the VLSI jargon so I just guessed. I think DonFusilli has better explanation as answer.

Comment: Isometric comes from greek, as did the ISO institute name, they just worked backwards from the acronym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iso is a Greek-derived prefix meaning "equal", with a pretty substantial history of use in scientific and mathematical contexts to mean "the same" (isomolar, isotropic, isostructure, isomorphism), or a line or surface along which some quantity is held constant (isobar, isotherm, isochron, isocline).

The name ISO is officially *not* an acronym (none of its official names start with those letters in that order, although its English name, "International Organization for Standardization", comes *close*); instead it's a pun on *iso* and the organization's role in promoting uniformity around the world.

Comment: Surely "International Standards Organization" is a *really* obvious English backronym.

Comment: @user253751 yes, and one they deliberately didn't choose, so as not to privilege English.

Answer (score 0):

It's just shorthand for *isometric*.

I guess that's too short an answer, so the Merriam-Webster definition of isometric:

> 1 : of, relating to, or characterized by equality of measure

So you're measuring different systems under the same circumstances so you can actually compare apples to apples.

Comment: As @Justme described in the comments on the question, it's worth noting that in general "iso" is a common prefix from Ancient Greek meaning "equal". So in this case I'm not sure if it's necessarily even shorthand (for "isometric")—"isofrequency" on its own can be understood as "equal frequency".